# Usage of ThreadLocal when no shared objects exist

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-local

I was given some code that contains some classes that use [TheadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

Here is a sample implementation:

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {
    }


    // Class methods..


    private static ThreadLocal<MyClass> factoryCache = new ThreadLocal<MyClass>() {
    public synchronized MyClass initialValue() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public synchronized MyClass get() {
        return super.get();
    }

    public synchronized void set(MyClass value) {
        super.set(value);
    }
    };

    public static MyClass get() {
    return factoryCache.get();
    }
}
```

Notice that in order to use the class the static getter is called: MyClass.get();
This ensure that I get an instance that corresponds to the current running thread.

My question - this class contains no members nor static variables, meaning there are no shared objects in the class level. In this case - I'm wondering if the use of ThreadLocal here has any advantage. Let's assume I use this class as a singletone (removing the ThreadLocal part), each thread will create its own stack when entering a method (right?), so is there a point of using ThreadLocal in such a case?

Additional info - this is a web application that handles many concurrent http requests and the issued class is used per http request.

Comment: Why not make all methods static and forget about singleton and thread local?

Comment: `ThreadLocal` allows you to have each MyClass instance per each thread. If thread modifies MyClass object then the same thread will have  modified MyClass object for subsequent `threadLocal.get()`

Comment: MyClass object becomes scoped per thread and on class level .

Comment: @Henry - This is a matter of style, personally I think that static methods are horrible since it's the exact opposite of object oriented design. But this is a different discussion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread safety is about shared state. If your class doesn't have any state to share between threads, you don't need to worry about thread safety.

So, if your class has no fields, you can safely share the same instance of the class between multiple threads (singleton), or even make all its methods `static` (as it's often done for various utility classes).

It won't cause any problem, because, as you correctly noted, each thread has its own stack, therefore local variables cannot be shared between threads in any way.

Comment: I guess this confirms my thoughts. Thanks